# Passing errors to C# if iText7 is unable to find the references

Tags: itext7

I have a program that converts HTML/JS/CSS to PDF using iText7. I want to stop the execution of the program should a stylesheet or script reference not be found.

This is what I am using now but it does not flag if the references aren't loaded/found:

```cs
static void ConvertHTMLtoPDF(string source_code, string output_file)
{
    //note-to-self: iText7 CANNOT HANDLE CSS CALCulations and Variables

    string executablePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    string HTMLFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(executablePath, source_code);
    string PdfFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(executablePath, output_file);

    //check if the source file exists
    if (!File.Exists(HTMLFilePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            "The source file: ["+ HTMLFilePath + "] does not exist, please check that your code is correct");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Valid Arguments; converting HTML to PDF...");

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(PdfFilePath);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(HTMLFilePath, FileMode.Open), pdfDocument);

    pdfDocument.Close();
}
```

I don't know how iText7 interacts with the code, whether it has access to errors from a browser like `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` which is logged to console if a reference isn't found or if it loads the CSS/JS references and could detect this itself.

Any suggestions or settings that could be used?